# switch's mgmt-ip is not remotely reachable

Tags: networking, vlan, netgear

Switch model: Netgear FSM7352PS
mgmt-ip: 192.168.1.100/24
Vlan id: 1 (default)

There are couple of hosts in this Vlan: 192.168.1.2 (esxi console), for instance.
192.168.1.1 is the firewall/router interface.

I can ping 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2 from other vlans, say, 172.31.0.0/24
I can ssh to 192.168.1.2 from 172.31.0.0/24

I can't ping 192.168.1.100 from 172.31.0.0/24
However, I can ping 192.168.1.100 from 192.168.1.2 or from my laptop connected to that vlan (192.168.1.11). I can connect to the web GUI from my laptop when I am in that Vlan.

Can anyone shed some light on why I am not able to connect from other vlans?

PS: on the switch, I see this entry in routing table, next hop IP for 192.168.31.0/24 is 192.168.31.100; when I connect to 192.168.31.2, it comes via 192.168.31.1 which is on fw/router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you setup routing between VLANs on your switch?  I don't believe that happens automatically, but I am not too familiar with Netgear switches.

Comment: Anyway, I added a route on the switch, it fixed the problem
0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 via 192.168.31.1